# knime youtube api search result next page

Tags: youtube-api, knime

I am using the example server provided by knime to get youtube search result. But I am only able to get maximum 50 results. how do I get access to more results?
https://www.knime.com/nodeguide/data-access/rest-web-services/access-youtube-rest-api

Answer (score 2):

Since it's using Youtube API, you'll be using **nextPageToken** to access the next results. So in your case that would be 51-100. The **prevPageToken** does the opposite.

> [**pageToken**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)
>
> The pageToken parameter identifies a specific page in the result set
>   that should be returned. In an API response, the nextPageToken and
>   prevPageToken properties identify other pages that could be retrieved.
>
> You can try here in [Google API
>   Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?id=Ks-_Mh1QhMc&part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics).

Authorize and Execute. If there's more than 50 result, you'll notice a nextPageToken in the JSON response. Place that in the "pageToken" property and execute again. You'll be given the 51-100 results. The same thing happens with 101-150 and so forth.